# xcode no suitable image found

Tags: swift, frameworks, xcode8

I'm running into following error

```
The bundle “Project-name” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.

Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/name/Documents/proj-name: required code signature missing for '/Users/name/Documents/proj-name/Frameworks/Project.framework/Project'
)
Program ended with exit code: 82
```

I've a dependency which itself a custom Framework file (library) and added this to current project but running into problem when I run a test.

Project compiles and builds fine, error appears when running tests.

Swift 3.0, XCode 8.0

Comment: may error related to your  Apple certificates. Try   clean your project`(CMD+Option+Shift+K)` or manually clean your project `DerivedData`.

Comment: sorry, same problem